# traceroute - What does it mean when !N appears next to a time measurement?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I am running a traceroute command to host [YYY.YYY.Y.Y], and at the output is as follows:

```
...
e1-25-20-cr-rt-bb2-area2.ns.uwaterloo.ca (ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ)  4.164 ms  6.741 ms  6.444 ms
 8  wms.uwaterloo.ca (MMM.MM.MMM.MM)  3.034 ms  3.612 ms  3.334 ms
 9  wms.uwaterloo.ca (MMM.MM.MMM.MM)  3.802 ms !N  5.354 ms !N  5.588 ms !N
```

Several sources have told me that !N means that the destination host is unreachable. However, this seems to be the case when the output is as follows:

`9  wms.uwaterloo.ca (129.97.208.23)  !N  !N  !N`

What does it mean when !N appears beside an elapsed time ?

I don't think I should be interpreting `{elapsed_time} !N` as destination unreachable since I was definitely able to reach my target destination through a web browser and through "ping".

Answer (score 0):

wms.uwaterloo.ca sends back an ICMP Destination network unreachable message. Some protocols and port used by your traceroute are filtered. If you can create a packet capture then you will see and understand what happens under the hood.